# how can I determine whether hibernate has 'lazy' loaded the proxy or the real object?

Tags: hibernate, lazy-evaluation

New to hibernate here. I'm using Hibernate 3.5, which I understand should use lazy fetching by default. I have SQL logging enabled via

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

I'm requesting object A which has a reference to object B which holds the actual byte array of data. I pushed the data into object B so that the data doesn't get fetched from the DB unless really needed, but when I request object A, the heap jumps drastically, as if it's fetched the data anyway, and I get this output from hibernate SQL logging:

```
Hibernate: select attachment0_.id as id11_0_, attachment0_.data as data11_0_ from attachment_data attachment0_ where attachment0_.id=?
```

I'm unclear on how to interpret this, specifically the 'as' statement. The 'attachment0.data' seems to be the byte array in object B. Is hibernate saying that it's created a proxy for the array, or is this saying it's actually pulled the data from the DB? If it's just created a proxy, would I see no select output for the proxy?

So in summary, the main question of how can I determine whether I have a proxy or real object, and the related question of how to interpret the select statement?

I have dived into the hibernate docs, as well as searched on the web quite a bit, but most of the info seems to be a step above the basic knowledge I'm missing, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: attachment_data is the table mapped to object A or object B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you have can be a proxy with all the data loaded. If your want to unproxy the object use the following in Hibernate:

From an `org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl` you can get the `org.hibernate.engine.PersistenceContext` and then

```
SessionImpl session = ...;
PersistenceContext persistenceContext = session.getPersistenceContext();
Object entity = persistenceContext.unproxy(maybeProxy);
```

The javadoc for unproxy

```
/**
 * Get the entity instance underlying the given proxy, throwing
 * an exception if the proxy is uninitialized. If the given object
 * is not a proxy, simply return the argument.
 */
public Object unproxy(Object maybeProxy) throws HibernateException;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. You say that the object can be a proxy with all the data loaded, but what would be the point in that? the object is really just a container holding data and methods, so what's the difference between a proxy and a real object, in the context of hibernate passing proxies vs real objects?

Comment: Let me clarify what I mean: first you get a proxied instance that is initialized on-demand either by `Session.load` (given that the data is not in the first level cache) or by browsing a relation. Then when a property of the proxy is accessed, the entity data is fetched from the database. The java object instance is still a proxy (be with all data loaded) and it will continue to be a proxy until you `unproxy` it. For hibernate you can use proxy or real object indifferently.

Comment: interesting, thanks. As long as the data and methods are the same, I suppose it doesn't really matter whether I'm dealing with a proxy or the real object then.

Comment: @Nr9: I would like to know the unproxy method of PersistenceContext object is deep or shadow? tks.